# Facebook API Search by phone number

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

So I have a huge list of phone numbers and want to find facebook users for each of the phone numbers if they exist.  There are tons of iphone apps, etc that pull in your contact list and match them to facebook accounts.  Any ideas on how I can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Jim

Comment: What does the API say?

Comment: Nothing.  I looked at the search sip and the user search says ou name.  Also looked at fql.   To be clear I don't want the number of the logged in user rather need to find a user based on a phone number

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: The way it should be done, it´s by doing a search, using the type user. https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=daniel&type=user but you cant type phone number instead characters, don´t understand why. Facebook limitations crap

Answer (score -1):

You will need to call the API 'login()' function with the permission "user_mobile_phone". You can then retrieve it as usual.

Here is the FB dev post and examples of doing this:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/01/14/platform-updates--new-user-object-fields--edge-remove-event-and-more/

Comment: According to that it was removed also I need to find a user based on phone which is different I think

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot get a FB user's phone number unless they authorize your app to do so. There are some users that have their phone shown as public information, and I believe a lot of systems which do what you are seeking just 'scrape' that data from the user's About page.

It's trivial for Google, who already indexes all of the Facebook pages for search, to associate this information for Android contacts.

Comment: Thank you.  This I understand.  My question and perhaps I was not clear is this.  I have a cell phone number, say, 5555551212.  I want to do a facebook search and find the user (if public) who has that phone number.  I dont need to see the number, just find the user tied to that phone number.